# Direction independent slicing

Tags: vhdl, slice

I'm creating a package with some functions I often use and some functions need to take slices of their parameters. I usually use `downto` direction for all my signals, but sometimes signals change their direction unexpectedly, e.g., appending a zero bit (`sig & '0'`) seems to change the direction to positive.

Is there a way to slice arrays (`std_logic_vector`, `unsigned`, `signed`) independent of their direction? For example how would you implement a function taking the lowest two bits? The only implementation I came up with uses an additional constant with the expected direction:

```
function take_two(x : std_logic_vector) return std_logic_vector is
    constant cx : std_logic_vector(x'length-1 downto 0) := x;
begin
    return cx(1 downto 0);
end function;
```

I've also tried something like `x(x'low+1 downto x'low)` but Quartus doesn't like this.

Comment: You could use an `alias` instead of a `constant`, but I think this is already the nicest solution.

Comment: A constant or an alias are the only "clean" solutions I know. There is another one, that uses type attributes, tests the direction, and compute the bounds of the slice, but it is so ugly...

Comment: The direction of expression `(sig & '0') ` is defined in IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.2.3 Adding operators para 2 b): *...and the direction of the index subtype of this implicit array is the direction of S, where S is the index subtype of the base type of the result* and the index subtype of std_logic_vector is natural and is ascending. One way to fix this is assignment (5.3.2.2 Index constraints and discrete ranges, para 4 "...assignment and certain other operations on arrays involve an implicit subtype conversion"). Aliases are lower overhead, they're just additional names.

Comment: VHDL arrays "know" their dimensions and direction and you can know as well using their `'left`, `'right`,`'low`, `'high` and `'ascending` attributes. If you need a 'backwards' alias as mentioned, the `'reverse_range` attribute can help you as well.

Answer (score 0):

The question is actually not on the input, but on the required output. What do you prefer?

If you look at how functions are implemented in for instance [`std_logic_1164-body.vhdl`](https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl/blob/master/libraries/ieee2008/std_logic_1164-body.vhdl), your function would similarly be something like (in a complete example):

```
entity e is end entity;
library ieee;
architecture a of e is
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    signal test : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "10010110";
    signal output : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);

    function slice(s: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR; u, l : natural) return STD_LOGIC_VECTOR is
        alias sv : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (s'length-1 downto 0) is s;
        variable result : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (u downto l);
    begin
        for i in result'range loop
            result(i) := sv(i);
        end loop;
        return result;
    end function;
begin
    output <= slice(test & '0', 5, 3); -- test becomes 'to' range.
    -- output still becomes "101"
end architecture;
```